# CSS rule for number greater than

Tags: html, css, numbers

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="positive">
<td class="happy">12</td>
<td class="happy">7</td>
<td class="happy">69</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

▲ this is the origin html code.

```
td.happy(@>10) {color:red;}
td.happy(@>50) {color:blue;}
```

▲ this is the css code what i want. (Imagine)

i'd like to apply CSS style when the number greater than specific number(10, 50)

i'v tried Java-script, and it worked, but i want to make the website only with html and CSS as possible.

Is there any way to select the text's number, which is in the tag?

Comment: Even if you were to do your own proper research on _can_ an element be selected based on its text content first (https://www.google.com/search?q=css+select+element+based+on+text+content), I doubt very much that you would find a way to get it to do a _mathematical comparison_ of string values as well.

Comment: If you are able to decide which elements are "positive" and "happy" based on value(?) to begin with, then you should also be able to classify these elements as happy-and-red or happy-and-blue in a way selectable to CSS as well ( such as, in the simplest form, an additional class; ideally based on what that information represents rather than currently desired formatting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with pure css,you must help of jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr.positive td.happy').each(function(){
    number = parseFloat($(this).text());
    if(number > 10)
      $(this).addClass('greater10');
    if(number > 50)
      $(this).addClass('greater50');
  })
})
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.greater10 {
  color: red;
}

.greater50 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="positive">
      <td class="happy">12</td>
      <td class="happy">7</td>
      <td class="happy">69</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), no.

You can match on an element, the name of an attribute in the element, and the value of a named attribute in an element. The only control you can do is if a tag is [empty](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Not from css, if you are trying to avoid a whole new js page then maybe consider embedding the js in your HTML.